# Microsoft Wireless 900 Desktop and iMac running 10.11.6

Tags: wifi, accessories

Will this desktop setup work with the iMac running 10.11.6?

Comment: iMac model?  What have you tried?  What have you researched?

Answer (score 1):

It "should" work.  From the [technical specifications page](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/wireless-desktop-900/pt3-00001#specsColumns-testCarousel):

> ### Computer
>
> Requires a PC that meets the requirements for and has installed one of
> these operating systems:
>
> - Windows 10 / 8 / 7
> - Mac OS X v10.4 – 10.7

It's just an USB HID (Human Interface Device).  Now, there may be certain keyboard/mouse functions that are not available due to the limited availability.